# How to create a dynamic prop name in React?

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to create the name of a prop dynamically? For example:

```
let dynamicPropName = "someString";

<MyComponent dynamicPropName="some value" />
```

so that inside MyComponent, this.props.someString exists.

Comment: Of course, provided `MyComponet` knows how to handle it. Otherwise it is of no use.

Comment: So what's the solution?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

If you are using **es6**, you can define the dynamic prop:

```
let dynamicProps = {"dynamicKey":"someString", "dynamicKey2":"someString"};
```

or

```
let someVariable = "xyz";
dynamicProps[someVariable] = value;
```

then use the spread operator:

```
<MyComponent {...dynamicProps} />
```

Inside MyComponent -

```
let props = {...this.props};
```

Now you can use `Object.keys` on `props` to get all dynamic prop names.

**Edit:**
Added an example

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  
  renderFromProps() {
    return Object.keys(this.props)
    .map((propKey) =>
      <h3>{this.props[propKey]}</h3>
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
      <h1>One way </h1>
      <hr/>
      <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
      <h3>{this.props.type}</h3>
      <h3>{this.props.value}</h3>
      <hr/>
     <h1> Another way </h1>
      <hr/>
      { this.renderFromProps()}
     </div>
   );
  }
  
}

const dynamicProps = { name:"Test", type:"String", value:"Hi" };

ReactDOM.render(
  <Test {...dynamicProps} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
</div>
```

Comment: When inside the component, how do I pick up the dynamic prop - ```this.props[someVariable]``` ?

Comment: You can access via individual prop name e.g `this.props.somveVariable`

Comment: Could you develop this answer with a demo (jsFiddle)?

Comment: @saawsann I have added an example to illustrate.

Comment: Not very important question, since I learned what I need to from your question, but what is `let props = ...this.props` for? I got `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...`

Answer (score 42):

It's possible to do this with JSX syntax alone with [spread attribute](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes) and [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```
<MyComponent {...{ [dynamicPropName]: "some value" }} />
```

Answer (score 12):

An inline way (very ugly and not recommended) is using a expression to define an `object`:

```
<input {...(el.required ? {required: true} : {})}>
```

Comment: You're example is contrived as it would normally just be `required={el.required}`, but for 
 real use-cases, I've used this multiple times, not just with React.