# How to chose a React component props depending on condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following React component:

```
<SweetAlert 
    show={this.props.message} 
    success 
    title={this.props.message}
    onConfirm={this.props.handleCloseAlert}>
</SweetAlert>
```

And this is the alert I get with it:

[image]

But I want the props `success` to be dynamically chosen at execution time, so I tried this:

```
 const alertType = () => {
    switch(this.props.type) {
        case ALERT_ERROR:
          return 'error'
        case ALERT_WARNING:
          return 'warning'
        case ALERT_DANGER:
          return 'danger'
        case ALERT_INFO:
          return 'info'
        case ALERT_SUCCESS:
          return 'success'
      }
    }

<SweetAlert 
    show={this.props.message} 
    {...alertType()}
    title={this.props.message}
    onConfirm={this.props.handleCloseAlert}>
</SweetAlert>
```

But I loose the alert type with it:

[image]

I haven't found a way for adding a discretional props to a component.

Comment: Is this the library you're using? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-sweetalert

Comment: @Dupocas Nope, I am using `material-ui`

Comment: Does material UI have a component called `SweetAlert`?

Comment: @Dupocas, You are right. I thought it was part of `material-ui`, but it is actually the library you are talking about

Comment: I'm asking because I can't find such a component inside mui's docs. And I never heard of it

Comment: ok then, now I can help you hahaha posting the answer

Comment: In case you ever want to achieve what you were initially asking for, here's [how to create a dynamic prop name in React](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40868189/1218980)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass `type` as the returned value of your function

```
<SweetAlert 
    show={this.props.message} 
    type={alertType()}
    title={this.props.message}
    onConfirm={this.props.handleCloseAlert}>
</SweetAlert>
```

[Source](https://github.com/djorg83/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/blob/0808e8578fc94d53c8ce80d45aeabce3d8f59208/src/components/SweetAlert.tsx#L390-L400) of why passing `success` as a boolean worked

Comment: Here's the [source code reference](https://github.com/djorg83/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/blob/0808e8578fc94d53c8ce80d45aeabce3d8f59208/src/components/SweetAlert.tsx#L390-L400) which shows exactly why this works.

Comment: As always thanks for improving the answer @EmileBergeron

Answer (score 2):

if u return a object for the component, like `{danger: true}`

```
switch(this.props.type) {
        case ALERT_ERROR:
          return {error: true}
        case ALERT_WARNING:
          return {warning: true}
        case ALERT_DANGER:
          return {danger: true}
        case ALERT_INFO:
          return {info: true}
        case ALERT_SUCCESS:
          return {success: true}
      }
    }
```

Comment: lol, strange, on the example, <Component success />, but i think u are correct, thanks :3

Comment: @FábioFialho OP was using the shortcut props, but there's a `type` prop just for this.

Answer (score 0):

Writing

```
<MyComponent myProp/>
```

is just a short hand notation for

```
<MyComponent myProp={true}/>
```

So changing `return 'error'` to `return {error: true}` should work for you

Comment: But it is not what I am looking for. What I want is to choose the name of the prop dynamically.

Comment: I'm talking about changing the value returned from the `switch` case in `alertType`