# How to create a dynamic prop name in react using functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, create-react-app, react-props, react-functional-component

This post has the answer I'm looking for but they are using outdated class based components and I need help translating them to functional. [How to create a dynamic prop name in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40868189/how-to-create-a-dynamic-prop-name-in-react). How would this post be written if answered using react functional components. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function Test(props) {
  const renderFromProps = () => {
    return Object.keys(props)
    .map((propKey) =>
      <h3>{props[propKey]}</h3>
    );
  };
  
  return (
   <div>
    <h1>One way </h1>
    <hr/>
    <h3>{props.name}</h3>
    <h3>{props.type}</h3>
    <h3>{props.value}</h3>
    <hr/>
    <h1> Another way </h1>
    <hr/>
    { renderFromProps()}
   </div>
 );
}

const dynamicProps = { name:"Test", type:"String", value:"Hi" };

ReactDOM.render(
  <Test {...dynamicProps} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
</div>
```