# How do I pass a variable on the graphql filter?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, graphql, dynamodb-queries

In the section below, `ref`, and `queryName` work fine (so long as you pass the full graphql query, and not just the name of it.  In any case, `columnName` does not seem to accept a variable as an input.  When the post request is examined, it just says "columnName" instead of id or whatever I happen to use as the search criteria when I specified columnName on the function call.

```
export async function fetchItems(ref, queryName, columnName) {
     const queryNameData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(queryName, {
          filter: {
               columnName: {
                    contains: ref,
               },
          }
     }))

     const { items } = queryNameData.data
     return (items)
}
```

Here is an example of the variables section of the graphql post to dynamodb:

```
{
    variables: {
        filter: {
            columnName: {
                contains: "062"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The queryName and ref are fine, but in the present case "columnName" should be "id" as that is what I set columName equal to for the function call.

Comment: not a graphql problem - just pure js, create/prepare object with variable named prop, use it later in API call

Comment: @xadm It's unclear how to handle a prop variable in this application.  Example: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40868189/how-to-create-a-dynamic-prop-name-in-react) 'variable prop example'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare `filter` object using passed params like:

```
export async function fetchItems(ref, queryName, columnName) {
     let filter = {};
     filter[columnName] = { contains: ref };
     const queryNameData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(queryName, { filter }))
```

Comment: Oh, I see now.  Many thanks.  That did the trick.